# Permanently Disable Save button and Enable Edit Button After Submit

Tags: php, jquery

I am working on a registration page that has two buttons. One that saves a user data and the other which should edit the data.

Before a user submits the data, only the "save" button should be active, meaning the "edit" one should be disabled.

After a user enters the data and successfully saves it to the database (implying that it has passed all the validation), the "save" button should be disabled permanently such that a user saves data to the database only once, after which the "edit" button becomes active to enable him/her to edit the data whenever he/she dims it fit.

I understand jquery is the most appropriate for such a case and your help will be highly appreciated. I have tried to search every where for help but I haven't succeeded.I am not that good in jquery, thus the reason I am seeking for the assistance. Thank you in advance.
The html script for the two buttons are as indicated below:

`<button type="button" class="buton" name="submit" id="btnOne">Save &raquo;</button>`

```
<button disabled id="btnTwo" type="buton" class="button" name="edit">Edit &raquo;</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form name='' id='' action='' method='post'>
        <input type='text' name='txt_category' id='category' value='Jhon' placeholder="Firstname"  disabled>
        <input type='text' name='txt_stage' id='stage' value='Smith' placeholder="Lastname" disabled>
        <select disabled>
            <option>Male</option>
             <option>Female</option>
        </select>
        <input type='checkbox' name='txt_approve' id='approve' value='$approve' disabled>
        <input type="button" name='edit' value='edit'>
        <input type="button" name='save' value='save'> 
 
        
    </form>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        
     $(document).ready(function(){

         $("form input[type=text],form input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled",true);

         $("input[name=edit]").on("click",function(){

                 $("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],select").removeAttr("disabled");
         })

         $("input[name=save]").on("click",function(){

             $("input[type=text],input[type=checkbox],select").prop("disabled",true);
         })
           
          

     })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you RishiKesh Kumar for the answer. However, I have tried the code you posted but my "save" button no longer submits data to the database, whereas the edit button remains disabled.

Comment: Thank you once again @RishiKesh Kumar for your answer. Indeed, the code works in disabling the text inputs and checkboxes as well as the save button, and the edit button is also active. However, I would appreciate if at the first time of the login, the text inputs as well as the save button are active to enable the user enter and save data by clicking on save. Thank you

Comment: Ok RishiKesh Kumar, I changed the "true" in this code:"$("form input[type=text],form input[type=checkbox]").prop("disabled",true);" to "false" and I think it is working well now, except that nothing is being submitted to the database. Even the php validation doesn't work anymore. Any help please? Thank you in advance